# Java poll() inside if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, linked-list, queue

I had a little question over the execution of functions inside of an if statement.

For example this list of `edges(integers)`, will all the values be removed from the list until it pull's 5 from the list, Or what will happen exactly ?

```
LinkedList<Integer> edges = new LinkedList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
        if(edges.poll() == 5){
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: The function `poll()` is equivalent to the `remove()` function. So at each time you are calling `edges.poll()`, one item of the list will be removed. And then, the `edges.size()` will be updated.

Comment: Just found that it indeed removes these items eventhough it's inside an if. Will still let unanswered, maybe someone has a reel explanation for it.

Comment: The fact that it's an `if` statement is not relevant. In order to tell if `edges.poll() == 5`, `poll` has to be called, and this removes the first item from the list. This won't get undone just because the value isn't `5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - *poll* removes the first item in the list and returns it. 
This will then be evaluated in your if statement.

On an unrelated note, it is worth mentioning that the size of *edges* will obviously change on every loop since polling *edges* reduces the element count by one. However, your for loop evaluates the size of *edges* exactly once - on entry. A better way to implement this would be to use a while loop, for example.

```
int i = 0;

while(i<edges.size())
{
    if(edges.poll() == 5)
    {
        break;
    }
    i++
}
```